# ngx-mqtt multiple subscription not happening

Tags: angular, mqtt, mqttnet

I am trying to connect to MQTT server manually and then subscribe to multiple topics. I am able to connect manually, but not able to connect multiple topics with same MQTT service.
Library used ngx-mqtt for Angular

Problem/Issue   :-  When try to connect to second Topic, Second topic will append to first Topic.

See pic below which is not working and  my MQTT server is rejecting my call as 2 Topics are appended in one request for 2nd Topic, this has been tried multiple ways in code given below.

[image]

See pic below which is working on another old code.

[image]

Very poor documentation of ngx-mqtt leads to ask question for MQTT.

Tried couple of things in my code below are 2 of them i.e.

### Create one observable as per documentation and subscribe

Created one Observable after adding both topics to it and then subscribe to it

```
  mqttServiceOpts1: IMqttServiceOptions = {
    connectOnCreate: false,
    hostname: 'example-mqtt.ca',
    port: 8090,
    path: '/mqtt',
    protocol: 'wss'
  }
  connetMqtt() {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.getmqttDetails()
        .subscribe((data) => {
         
            console.log(data.port)
            console.log(data.clientId)
            console.log(data.broker)
            this.mqttServiceOpts1.clientId = data.clientId
            this.mqttService.connect(this.mqttServiceOpts1);

            const responsePustatusName= data.rootTopic + '/pustatus/inbox/+/response';
            const vacateRooutetopicName= data.rootTopic + '/vacateroute/wc/+/route/response';
            console.log('Response Topic Name ' + responsePustatusName);

           this.obs1$ = this.mqttService.observe(responsePustatusName)
           this.obs1$ = this.mqttService.observe(vacateRooutetopicName)
            this.subs2$ = this.obs1$.subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
              console.log('msg: ', message.payload.toString())
              });
              
          })
          resolve(true)
        })
    }
```

### Created 2 different observables

```
 mqttServiceOpts1: IMqttServiceOptions = {
    connectOnCreate: false,
    hostname: 'exmp-mqtt.ca',
    port: 8090,
    path: '/mqtt',
    protocol: 'wss'
  }
  connetMqtt() {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.getmqttDetails()
        .subscribe((data) => {
         
            console.log(data.port)
            console.log(data.clientId)
            console.log(data.broker)
            this.mqttServiceOpts1.clientId = data.clientId
            this.mqttService.connect(this.mqttServiceOpts1);

            const responsePustatusName= data.rootTopic + '/pustatus/inbox/+/response';
            const vacateRooutetopicName= data.rootTopic + '/vacateroute/wc/+/route/response';
            console.log('Response Topic Name ' + responsePustatusName);

           this.subs1$ = this.mqttService.observe(responsePustatusName).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
              console.log('msg: ', message)
            });
            this.subs2$ = this.mqttService.observe(vacateRooutetopicName).subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
              console.log('msg: ', message)
              });
              
          })
          resolve(true)
        })
    }
```